# Jekyll: Liquid Exception: failed to allocate memory in <file>

Tags: jekyll

I'm running Jekyll 3.5.1, Liquid 4.0.0, Ruby 2.2 on Windows 7.

When I run `jekyll serve`. It throws the below error.

```
Liquid Exception: failed to allocate memory in <file>
```

I've reinstalled Ruby, Jekyll and Liquid, but in vain. Any idea on how to fix this?

**Update:** I tried this on a different machine. Now, it throws the below error.

```
Liquid Exception: string sizes too big in <file>

jekyll 3.4.5 | Error:  string sizes too big
```

It seems like problem lies in my code. Not sure, where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Are you by chance using the paginate feature?